# PHP stop ignore_user_abort process

Tags: php, loops, process, abort

I was testing something that ran an `ignore_user_abort` process. Now it's running forever and I don't know how to handle or close it. Is it possible to access them through the terminal? Also, I'm running Apache.

Comment: are you running it through cli? Also What OS / Web server you have?

Comment: tried restarting apache?

Comment: okay, restarting solved it but i want to handle them one by one and not shutting them all by restarting for future uses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how is it possible ?

```
exit;
```

> and is it possible to access them through terminal ?

No. You could try to open a socket, or something like that, and then communicate with the process indirectly, but usually there is no real use-case for that.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the correct one if running on webserver is quite hard. Restarting will kill all php scripts running on that webserver.

If you were running them on cli you could identify process id and kill it.

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php for getting PHP's process ID